# Multiple onClick action

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, onclick

I'm new in Android code and, well, I have a big question.

Someone can explain me how can I give an object different actions with a number of clicks?

I'm building an app and I want to do that: when you touch a view element 2 times (for example), this element change to another activity, and when you touch it 4 times, that app could send an SMS.

I have all the functions completed, but I don't know how to make that "touch actions".

Someone can help me please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: In button onclick**

```
private int count = 0;
public void onClick(View v){  

switch(v.getId == R.id.btn){

   count++;

   switch(count){
      case 2:
        //Two clicks
      break;
      case 4:
        //Three clicks
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your example, and I could reach the 2 clicks but get more is imposible. How can I make a pause to listen all the clicks and then send the result to the switch

Comment: Well, finally I found a... quick solution. I use an IF to get the counter to send an SMS and to open the settings Activity I used an onLongClickListener(), Thanks for all! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private int click_count = 0;
public void onClick(View v){
    count++;

   switch(count){
      case 2:
        //Two clicks
      break;
      case 4:
        //Three clicks
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, I suggest you to clear the counter after 2 seconds or so.